# pgfplotstable: Have every other row be a multicolumn

Tags: pgfplotstable, multicolumn

I am trying to make a table using `pgfplotstable`, and am having difficulties because the `csv`'s are jagged. Most rows have 4 columns, as do the headers, but some rows are only 1 column and I would like these 1-cell rows to span the width of the table.

How do I either have `pgfplotstable` dynamically create multicolumns depending on the csv, or set every other row to be a multicolumn using data from the csv?

mwe (does not produce the proper layout):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,multirow,booktabs}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
    ColumnHeader1, ColumnHeader2, ColumnHeader3, ColumnHeader4
    item1, string1, string2, string3
    some-text-goes-here
    item2, string1, string2, string3
    some-more-text-goes-here
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep = comma,
    column type = l,
    string type,
    multicolumn names,
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    %every other row/.style = {\multicolumn{4}{l}{...}}
]{data.csv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a minimal working example (MWE), not not just a fragment. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass and ending with \end{document}

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have multicolumns by default, with the exception of the head row and possibly other exceptions, you can hack "typeset cell" from the columns.

The default is:

```
\ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=\pgfplotstablecols%
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{#1\\}%
\else%
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{#1 &}%
\fi%
```

And you make it out of it:

```
\pgfplotstableset{
typeset cell/.code={%% 
\ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=-1% Head Row (Exception)
  \ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=\pgfplotstablecols%
  \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{#1\\}%
  \else%
  \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{#1 &}%
   \fi%
\else
\ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=2% Another Exception Row ...
  \ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=\pgfplotstablecols%
  \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{#1\\}%
  \else%
  \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{#1 &}%
  \fi%
\else%
\ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=\pgfplotstablecols% Standard
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\\}%
\else%
\ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=1%
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\multicolumn{4}{c}{#1}}%
\else%
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
\fi\fi\fi\fi%
},%%
}
```

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt,]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs, filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12} 

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-data.csv}
A,B,C,D
Some Text goes here in a multicolum.,    ,   ,    
string1 (bad), string2, string3, string4
string1 (good), string2, string3, string4
Some more Text goes here in a multicolum.,    ,   ,    
Some Text goes here in a multicolum.,    ,   ,    
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableset{
typeset cell/.code={%% 
\ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=-1% Head Row (Exception)
  \ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=\pgfplotstablecols%
  \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{#1\\}%
  \else%
  \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{#1 &}%
   \fi%
\else
\ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=2% Another Exception Row ...
  \ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=\pgfplotstablecols%
  \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{#1\\}%
  \else%
  \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{#1 &}%
  \fi%
\else%
\ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=\pgfplotstablecols% Standard
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\\}%
\else%
\ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=1%
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\multicolumn{4}{c}{#1}}%
\else%
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
\fi\fi\fi\fi%
},%%
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep = comma,
string type, 
column type = l,
multicolumn names,
every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
]{\jobname-data.csv}
\end{document}
```